# why am I getting format exception in this code? It has one argument only

Tags: c#

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string val;
    if (blower)
        val = "Yes";
    else
        val = "No";
    return string.Format(
                   "With Blower \t:\t {0} \n" +
                   val);
}
```

I am getting an exception in these lines:-

```
 return string.Format(
                "With Blower \t:\t {0} \n" +
                val);
```

The exception is:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18):

Use it this way:

```
string.Format("With Blower \t:\t {0} \n", val);
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you meant

```
return string.Format("With Blower \t:\t {0} \n", val);
                                               ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean to use a comma instead of a concatenation?

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify this entire method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("With Blower \t:\t {0} \n", blower ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace the + with a comma maybe:

```
 return string.Format(
                "With Blower \t:\t {0} \n",
                val);
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey SO is no race, is it? ^^ I sometimes get this feeling, but as long as there is one correct answer, the author of the question should be happy. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe SO could automatically determine similarity of answers and collapse all but the first. ^^

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer In theory there could be a 'vote to merge' added.

Answer (score 1):

Try separating by a comma:

return string.Format(
                "With Blower \t:\t {0} \n",
                val);

Answer (score 0):

Use comma instead of concatenation

```
return string.Format("With Blower \t:\t {0} \n",  val);
```